# Кэшируется при выключенном кэшировании Bitrix

Tags: php, битрикс

Есть компонент который выбирает город и на основе выбранного города показывает товары из инфоблока города. 
Компонент кэшируется при выключенном кэшировании на всём сайте и даже на самом элементе. Соответсвенно показывает элементы инфоблока не из выбранного инфоблока,а который отображается. 
Компонент работает верно, если активна админка,а у рядового пользователя она не работает.
Есть строка $this->__component->SetResultCacheKeys(array('ALL')); , который при выключении теряется город.

ResultModifier

```
$this->__component->SetResultCacheKeys(array('ALL'));
//$this->__component->SetResultCacheKeys(array('IBLOCK_SECTION_ID'));
$this->__component->arResult['ALL']=$arResult;
```

Component_epilog

```
$arResult=$arResult['ALL'];
```

Answer (score 0):

Найдите в коде компонента функцию StartResultCache, у него есть параметр additionalCacheID который определяет id кеша.
По умолчанию параметр равен False, т.е. кеш зависит только от текущего сайта SITE_ID, имени компонента, имени шаблона и входных параметров $arParams. Поэтому добавьте параметр определяющий город, например $arParams["CITY"].

https://dev.1c-bitrix.ru/api_help/main/reference/cbitrixcomponent/startresultcache.php

Answer (score 0):

Component_epilog исполняется после того, как отработал result_modifier и template, т.е. после шаблона. Для того, чтобы передать в component_epilog.php что-то из шаблона и используют

```
$this->__component->SetResultCacheKeys(array('ALL'));
//$this->__component->SetResultCacheKeys(array('IBLOCK_SECTION_ID'));
$this->__component->arResult['ALL']=$arResult;
```

Это просто "проброс" недостающих данных в component_epilog